# Создание системы уведомлений на сайте

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, алгоритм

Есть потребность в создании системы уведомлений на сайте. Внешне это выглядит вот так:

[image: изображение]
<sub>(источник: [khvorostin.com](http://i.khvorostin.com/img/notifications.png))</sub>

Сообщения добавляются на страницу при помощи jQuery, который берет данные в JSON и собирает из них блоки. Страница, которая отдает JSON собирает данные при загрузке страницы от разных проверяльщиков.

*И вот здесь у меня возникла сложность с полным пониманием того, как оно должно работать. Не знаю, какое выражение соответствует у программистов фразе "глаз замылился" - тут именно что нужен свежий взгляд.*

Ситуация 1. Пользователь закрыл уведомление. При открытии следующей страницы снова появятся те же уведомления. Если сделать обновление через временной интервал, то одни и те же уведомления будут подгружаться снова и снова.

Ситуация 2. Пользователь не уходит со страницы.

В обоих случаях меня интересует, как лучше отфильтровать новые уведомления от уже показанных - чтобы показать только новые.

Comment: Так а нельзя сделать, чтобы JS-скрипт при закрытии уведомления (ручном или автоматическом по прошествии времени висения) отсылал с `id` (или типа того) увдомления запрос, чтобы в БД стёрлось уведомление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предположить, что используются кукисы. Внешний вид уведомлений напоминет плагин **jgrowl**, который может работать с другим плагинам **jquery-cookie**, что встречается довольно часто. Поэтому, для начала, я бы покопал в эту сторону.

P.S. Если моя догадка верна, то для фильтрации добавляйте время внесения куков и проверяйте и проверяйте по этому времени перед их выводом.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. В настоящий момент ничего в кукисы не пишется - только добавляются блоки с уведомлениями на страницу. 

jgrowl и jquery-cookie поизучаю в плане логики работы. На скриншоте  - результат работы своего кода, без дополнительных jQuery-плагинов. Сделал оформление по типу тех, которые нравились.

Comment: сделайте в базе у уведомлений три состояния - "новое","было показано" и "было прочитано" первое при получении события,  второе - когда ajax спросил, третье когда нажали в область уведомления (если такая есть)